# How do I do assembly language encrypt/decrypt programming?

Tags: assembly, x86

This is an encryption routine to encrypt a character:

Can anybody shine some light on the decryption routine?

Edit (see comments):

Comment: Would it be possible for you to tell us more details on the parameters? What values do EAX and ECX contain, which of them contains the character to encode?

Comment: I think I came late, but.. what was the question?

Answer (score 1):

This is the first block that we can decrypt :

```
xor eax,edx 
xor eax,ecx 
rol al,1
```

That is because the values are poped from stack. This is reversible like :

```
ror al,1
xor eax, ecx (eax = the one we had in the end)
xor eax, edx
```

Then edx = eax (mov edx,eax). And now :

```
dec eax
rol eax, 1
rol eax, 1
```

and the last AND cannot be reversed because :

```
? AND 0 = 0
? AND 1 = 1  => ? = 1
? AND 1 = 0  => ? = 0
```

? can not be identified UNLESS there is no *? AND 0 = 0* combination.

Comment: Sure? The original values are preserved with the PUSHes and re-introduced later with the POPs... The part with the AND looks to me somehow if it's calculating a "key" for the encryption.

Comment: Thought about it a bit more. Could it be, that eax contains the encryption key and ecx is the character to encode? I did not have the time yet to verify but do you think it would be possible to re-calculate the ecx if eax is given on the decryption?

Comment: ecx is most probably a given attribute, probably the key. eax seems to be the ch code. Still, i don't see how AND can be reversed.

Comment: but if ecx is the character code, reversing is very easy, since ecx is popped in the very end. But i don't think that's the case.

Comment: ecx is popped as eax and vice versa

Comment: It doesn't matter whether eax or ecx is popped first, because xor is commutative. there are 3 values xor'd together: `eax`, `ecx` and `((eax&0x3c)>>2)+1`. The other post says eax is a character from the key and ecx is the character code. So the decrypt routine is nearly the same as the encrypt. Only the `rol al, 1` must be removed and therefore a `ror cl, 1` must be added before the first two pushs.

Comment: right rudi-moore. I guess one would have to put it in an assembler to try it anyway. But overall, the idea is the same.

Comment: @SpyrosP: no ecx must be character code in the other case some characters should have the same decode result!

Comment: the thing is that if ecx is the character code, then the decryption routine is just one ror and a xor :) To tell you the truth, i think that eax is the character code, but whatever the case is, every possibility has been discussed :) And the author of the question does not reply back :D

Comment: the eax is the encyption key value and the ecx is the character to be encrypted

Answer (score 0):

Let's see:
In order to decrypt the message we want to reverse the encryption procedure, so let's start at the end of the method:

the last part of the transformation is `rol al, 1`. This we can reverse as `ror al, 1`.

The rest of the encryption consists of two xors, one of the message and with a modified key and one with the immediate result and the original key. Since xor is self inverting we can reverse this by xoring the encrypted message once with the original key and once with the modified key (using the same key modification function).

All in all the follwing should reverse the encryption:

```
decrypt: ror cl,1 //reverse rol al, 1
         xor ecx, eax //reverse xor message, original key
         and eax,0x3C //calculate modified key
         ror eax,1 
         ror eax,1 
         inc eax      //end calculate modified key
         xor eax, ecx //reverse xor message modified key
         ret
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the `ROL` the encryption decryption could have been used for decryption, too.
Assuming the encrypted character is in `ecx` and the key in `eax`, it only needs a small modification:

```
  decrypt5: 
      push eax 
      push ecx
```

This part generates an internal key in `edx` from the input key in `eax`:

```
      and eax,0x3C 
      ror eax,1 
      ror eax,1 
      inc eax 
      mov edx,eax
```

Pop the input character from `ecx` into `eax`:

```
      pop eax
```

Reverse the `ROL AL,1`:

```
      ror al,1
```

Undo the XOR-ing.
XOR is an involution, that is it is its own inverse.
It is also commutative, so the order doesn't matter:

```
      xor eax,edx
```

Pop the input key from `eax` into `ecx` and XOR:

```
      pop ecx 
      xor eax,ecx 

      ret
```

I hope is correct, my x86 assembly is rather rusty.

Note that it is a bit of a stretch to call this encryption.
It is so weak I'd rather call it obfuscation.